# How to start c program at start up in beaglebone black

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I want to start the c program automatically in beaglebone black when my beaglebone black start-up. I am able to start my c program for blinking the external led on start up but i am unable to start another c program.
After starting the service i am getting following output when i see the status of service

```
enter code here
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hello.service; disabled)
  Active: inactive (dead) since Mon, 24 Nov 2014 12:48:04 +0000; 2s ago
 Process: 3074 ExecStart=/usr/bin/hello.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  CGroup: name=systemd:/system/hello.service.
```

It is showing that service is loaded but it is inactive
Anyone plz help...

Comment: This service started a shell script (not a C program). The shell script exited with success.

Comment: But in my shell script I have mention tho start my c program.this is my .sh shell script                                            #!/bin/bash                                                           /path of my compiled c program/